# Multilingual drupal sites and... tag filtering?

Tags: drupal

I'd like to build a multilingual site and I am quite new to drupal, I was wondering if I could proceed in the following way:

I could tag my entries with the world "english" and "italian", then I could display pages only with such tags to filter my site...

Generally speaking, would I be able to filter my site by tag?

Would this option be feasible? What would be the best solution to my problem?

Many thanks for any answer!

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://drupal.org/node/275705 (Tutorial)

http://drupal.org/project/i18n (best module for this)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm going to check those out! What about tagging though? would it be feasible to filter a page based on tags?

Comment: when you create the node or the content you can select the language you want this node/content to appear in ... but i don't know if this module support tagging or not..im sorry :)